# docker run vs docker-compose one of these things is not like the other

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

I have an nginx proxy setup with a shellscript that looks something like this

```
docker run --detach --name nginx-proxy --publish 80:80 --publish 443:443 --volume /etc/nginx/certs \
--volume /etc/nginx/vhost.d --volume /usr/share/nginx/html --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro --restart unless-stopped jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
echo proxy up
docker run --detach --name nginx-proxy-letsencrypt --volumes-from nginx-proxy --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
--restart unless-stopped jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
echo ssl companion up

docker run -d \
-e VIRTUAL_HOST=[domain] \
\-e "LETSENCRYPT_HOST=[domain]" \
-e "LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=[emailaddress]" \
--name [domain] \
--expose 80 \
--restart always \
-v /code/[domain]:/var/www/html \
fauria/lamp


    echo test site up at [domain]
```

and this site works properly and functions as expected.
I then stop the web server container and use the following docker-compose.yaml and it fails with a 502..

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  lamp:
    restart: always
    image: fauria/lamp
    container_name: [domain]
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /code/[domain]:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=[domain]
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=[domain]
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=[emailaddress]
```

Why? Aren't they the same? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i was not connecting my docker-compose to the bridge network used by default in the proxy image.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  lamp:
    restart: always
    image: fauria/lamp
    network-mode: bridge
    container_name: [domain]
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /code/[domain]:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=[domain]
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=[domain]
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=[emailaddress]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use docker-compose, docker-compose creates a docker network for you, in which all of the services can communicate with each other. Since you simply stopped the container and started it with docker-compose, now it does not have access to the containers on your localhost. This is why you get the 502 error. What you need to do is add the other containers to your docker compose file, and make sure you are connecting to the hosts using the proper service name (instead of localhost use http://service_name:443). Alternatively you can somehow give the containers in your docker network access to your localhost, but I'm not sure how to do this. Maybe you need to use 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1?